# Reaction of Tollen's reagent with 7‐oxabicyclo[2.2.1]heptan‐1‐ol

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

> Identify whether the given compound will get oxidised by Tollen's reagent.
>
> [image: 7‐oxabicyclo[2.2.1]heptan‐1‐ol]

The problem here is with the bridged alpha carbon. It cannot pertain sp<sup>2</sup> character in the middle of the reaction as it is not permittable according to Bredt's rule.

Comment: Is the answer given, yes? I too think you are right, and also, tollen's reagent oxidises only compounds with free CHO group, like aldehydes and alpha hydroxy ketones, so why should this give positive tollen's test?

Comment: I agree. I think this will not get oxidised by Tollens

Comment: The structure shown is 7-oxabicyclo[2.2.1]heptan-4-ol, which exists as 4-hydroxycyclohexanone, and not the title compound, 7-oxabicyclo[2.2.1]heptan-3-ol. Neither compound will be oxidized by Tollen's reagent (cc. @Waylander).

Comment: The answer given was incorrect and even I thought so. Now it's cleared

Comment: @AbhishekP If you got your answer, feel free to self-answer it. Self-answering is always encourages and it will help future readers.